# How to make requests to connect to third party APIs in Vapor?

Tags: swift3, vapor

In the Vapor framework for server side swift, I would like to respond to a request with info I got from third party API. For example, I receive a get request asking for the temperature of a city, and I want to connect to yahoo whether API to get the temperature then send it back. Do I need to download packages like Alamofire? Or Is there a built in way to do so in Vapor?

Comment: Please add additional details. Your question is not clear.

Comment: @NileshSingh hi, I'm sorry for the unclear question. I have updated the question. Hope it helps

Comment: @naif in your [next question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41513191/284120) you appear to be using `drop.client`. At StackOverflow, if an answer helps you, it's suggested that you mark it 'accepted' using the tick mark button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a built-in HTTP client in Vapor; it is called [`Client`](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/http/client.html).

To make a `GET` request to your third party API:

```
let apiResponse = try drop.client.get("https://api.com")
```

You can pass your query parameters in the query string, or using the convenient dictionary method:

```
let apiResponse = try drop.client.get("https://api.com", query: ["q": queryString])
```

`Client` also supports `POST`, or any other HTTP method.

Comment: Would some sort of Promises implementation be required since there is no immediate response available?

Comment: @DylanReich `drop.client` returns synchronously. If you're combining data from two or more remote APIs, then you'd want to use Promises (or simply GCD) to run the requests in parallel and return together.