# Deploying Vapor with heroku

Tags: swift, heroku, swift3, vapor

I have created a very simple app with one route in `main.swift`. It reads a city from a query string and use it to get the weather (through the yahoo API) of that city. this is the route:

```
drop.get("whether") { request in


    guard let city = request.data["city"]?.string else {
        return try JSON(node: ["Error": "no city given"])
    }

    return try drop.client.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22\(city)%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
}
```

The code works perfectly when I run it on localhost, but I get a 500 error when I deploy it with Heroku.

Is there  any file that I shouldn't be pushing to heroku? I want to note that in `server.json` the host value is `0.0.0.0`.

This is my Heroku logs (note that I redeployed it multiple times. all of which didn't work):

```
2017-01-05T17:00:28.932559+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=10bd5717-a444-4106-9479-5dda7de686d1 fwd="94.77.202.2" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=500 bytes=138
2017-01-05T17:00:34.568980+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=88277ee9-5814-4e33-a180-69e2a36a10ac fwd="94.77.202.2" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=161
2017-01-05T17:00:50.620499+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=e9e03939-3252-4eb2-ba05-ed06b7123fc0 fwd="94.77.202.2" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=500 bytes=138
2017-01-05T17:03:30.089070+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=d3334e79-bdaf-4f51-a6fe-198a356c2c8a fwd="94.77.202.2" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=31ms status=500 bytes=138
2017-01-05T17:03:41.773239+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=cb0f1bca-7538-497b-b1f2-6af9756c80f4 fwd="94.77.202.2" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=6ms status=503 bytes=0
2017-01-05T17:03:41.855395+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-01-05T17:03:41.856485+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-01-05T17:03:41.842156+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 132
2017-01-05T17:03:45.147623+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=25036`
2017-01-05T17:03:48.789403+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-01-05T17:04:29.863680+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=82133ef0-4539-4095-b3a9-e4d0c4bc709c fwd="94.77.202.2" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=119
2017-01-05T17:04:38.544040+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=258ab0c8-df6e-4ad2-a220-cb27f854a1bd fwd="94.77.202.2" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=119
2017-01-05T17:05:43.705482+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 132
2017-01-05T17:05:43.718722+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-01-05T17:05:43.608207+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=1a343b3b-963e-45b0-9795-1f83351b0100 fwd="94.77.202.2" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=503 bytes=0
2017-01-05T17:08:54.112283+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=5fcfc4a8-d8da-4e45-b8d1-99a8c14c1529 fwd="94.77.202.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-01-05T17:10:34.292205+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=75035a40-c1ca-4fc9-8cd1-10f73c5a4b84 fwd="94.77.202.2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-01-05T17:17:45.483824+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-01-05T17:17:45.483833+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2017-01-05T17:17:45.350717+00:00 app[api]: Deploy c3d8250 by user naifdev@gmail.com
2017-01-05T17:17:45.350717+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user naifdev@gmail.com
2017-01-05T17:17:45.706244+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-01-05T17:17:48.678813+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=53088`
2017-01-05T17:17:52.352793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-01-05T17:18:25.670087+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=9cec4496-95c5-4157-8dea-002310af4eaf fwd="94.77.202.2" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=27ms status=500 bytes=138
2017-01-05T17:51:55.253360+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-01-05T17:51:55.254766+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-01-05T17:51:55.780574+00:00 app[web.1]: No command supplied, defaulting to serve...
2017-01-05T17:51:55.780578+00:00 app[web.1]: Server 'default' starting at 0.0.0.0:53088
2017-01-05T17:51:55.780562+00:00 app[web.1]: Production mode enabled, disabling informational logs.
2017-01-05T17:51:55.780575+00:00 app[web.1]: No preparations.
2017-01-05T17:51:55.780579+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] Mozilla certificates have been deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Using 'defaults' instead.
2017-01-05T17:51:55.774837+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-01-05T17:51:55.895627+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 15
2017-01-05T18:01:48.893674+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2017-01-05T18:01:48.893975+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-01-05T18:01:53.364634+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=21483`
2017-01-05T18:01:57.090891+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-01-05T18:01:58.019181+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=ed174181-b3c9-4196-bd39-29121c343ea6 fwd="94.77.202.2" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=41ms status=500 bytes=138
2017-01-05T18:34:12.945697+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-01-05T18:34:12.946307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-01-05T18:34:13.855518+00:00 app[web.1]: Production mode enabled, disabling informational logs.
2017-01-05T18:34:13.855528+00:00 app[web.1]: No command supplied, defaulting to serve...
2017-01-05T18:34:13.855529+00:00 app[web.1]: No preparations.
2017-01-05T18:34:13.855530+00:00 app[web.1]: Server 'default' starting at 0.0.0.0:21483
2017-01-05T18:34:13.855531+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] Mozilla certificates have been deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Using 'defaults' instead.
2017-01-05T18:34:13.848202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-01-05T18:34:13.932737+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 15
2017-01-06T07:44:31.444744+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2017-01-06T07:44:31.444992+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-01-06T07:44:34.523300+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=31252`
2017-01-06T07:44:36.676936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-01-06T07:44:37.549125+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=0355d39f-cda9-4f8b-888b-18082332a824 fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=26ms status=500 bytes=138
2017-01-06T07:50:51.627447+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=11ee0882-1bd1-43a2-a0cc-4bc1c11f74eb fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=27ms status=500 bytes=138
2017-01-06T07:57:45.954329+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=e4ca9186-fdc5-4cd8-b98b-cfee45c7f3b2 fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=213ms status=500 bytes=138
2017-01-06T08:04:00.591772+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=b664a4c2-5aef-43b8-9c9f-180dfabeb93d fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=500 bytes=138
2017-01-06T08:04:57.818556+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=4ea215b8-a0a3-4ad0-9d8a-45fe27dbafd0 fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=119
2017-01-06T08:04:58.069106+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=04affbf0-ded7-4eb1-845c-e569aa31107c fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=161
2017-01-06T08:05:26.089377+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=3c5ba6df-acec-4b27-a3f4-e3c0f27941c2 fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=400ms status=500 bytes=138
2017-01-06T08:05:32.043519+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=9d35561a-633b-42c9-8fb6-6ec423bf667c fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=119
2017-01-06T08:05:40.163170+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/huguh" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=7a11db63-7644-4e42-a662-e223cb154171 fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=119
2017-01-06T08:13:43.406289+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=f672e00b-db30-484c-a5da-01f8e57022f4 fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=161
2017-01-06T08:13:55.835147+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=adb06e24-72cc-4b79-9d23-8a5ea127d2a3 fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=161
2017-01-06T08:45:25.599867+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-01-06T08:45:25.600941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-01-06T08:45:26.264901+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-01-06T08:45:26.280223+00:00 app[web.1]: Production mode enabled, disabling informational logs.
2017-01-06T08:45:26.280240+00:00 app[web.1]: No command supplied, defaulting to serve...
2017-01-06T08:45:26.280241+00:00 app[web.1]: No preparations.
2017-01-06T08:45:26.280241+00:00 app[web.1]: Server 'default' starting at 0.0.0.0:31252
2017-01-06T08:45:26.280242+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] Mozilla certificates have been deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Using 'defaults' instead.
2017-01-06T08:45:26.280243+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] Mozilla certificates have been deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Using 'defaults' instead.
2017-01-06T08:45:26.280244+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] Mozilla certificates have been deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Using 'defaults' instead.
2017-01-06T08:45:26.280244+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] Mozilla certificates have been deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Using 'defaults' instead.
2017-01-06T08:45:26.280245+00:00 app[web.1]: unable to load path
2017-01-06T08:45:26.280246+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] Mozilla certificates have been deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Using 'defaults' instead.
2017-01-06T08:45:26.280246+00:00 app[web.1]: unable to load path
2017-01-06T08:45:26.369735+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 15
2017-01-06T18:01:52.724336+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2017-01-06T18:01:52.724823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-01-06T18:01:56.197941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=51652`
2017-01-06T18:01:59.779285+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-01-06T18:02:00.857405+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/whether" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=39353fc7-8f70-49b4-95b0-12b4f2e0980a fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=161
2017-01-06T18:36:26.460178+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-01-06T18:36:26.460594+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-01-06T18:36:27.237564+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-01-06T18:36:27.390324+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 15
2017-01-06T18:36:27.262126+00:00 app[web.1]: Production mode enabled, disabling informational logs.
2017-01-06T18:36:27.262141+00:00 app[web.1]: No command supplied, defaulting to serve...
2017-01-06T18:36:27.262142+00:00 app[web.1]: No preparations.
2017-01-06T18:36:27.262143+00:00 app[web.1]: Server 'default' starting at 0.0.0.0:51652
2017-01-06T19:13:59.497901+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-01-06T19:13:59.497911+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2017-01-06T19:13:59.336403+00:00 app[api]: Deploy fa16ad6 by user naifdev@gmail.com
2017-01-06T19:13:59.336403+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user naifdev@gmail.com
2017-01-06T19:13:59.722058+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-01-06T19:14:02.835500+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `App --env=production --workdir=./ --config:servers.default.port=8308`
2017-01-06T19:14:06.609232+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-01-06T19:14:38.480190+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/whether?city=Paris" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=26c5f8bb-eb3b-47be-8fd2-799dfc4aed66 fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=500 bytes=138
2017-01-06T19:17:53.744114+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/whether?city=Paris" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=8414a869-8d81-480a-8a74-51cfb3644bbf fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=221ms status=500 bytes=138
2017-01-06T19:18:06.721140+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/whether?city=Paris" host=dry-beyond-95031.herokuapp.com request_id=04a1b568-bfe1-4643-9a34-fce7b23eb325 fwd="94.99.227.109" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=22ms status=500 bytes=138
```

Comment: Is it the root of the site, or `/whether` where you get the 500 error?

Comment: It seems like you have a number of Vapor-related questions. Consider joining the [Vapor Slack chat](http://vapor.team/) where there's almost always someone helpful around to assist.

Comment: I have this same problem. It's happening on the root route. Nothing specific, its just failing when trying to do a client external call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A user in the Slack channel gave me insight to this problem.:

VZSG:
@animatronicgopher: experimenting on Heroku is cheap but it's pretty pointless to scale up to paid dynos just because of this. It does *not* make a difference – first, this error is generated by an HTTP *client*, so your server's certificate doesn't matter, and second, even free dynos have proper certs (and they aren't just letsencrypt certs either). What you probably found is for custom domains.

The actual problem is that the "default" HTTPClient does not care about the dyno's trusted root certificates, therefore the outgoing SSL connection cannot be verified -> error.

Also, there's an issue in GitHub that gives you a sample of how to use FoundationClient. 
https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/699

Answer (score -2):

How to create swift backend API  with help of Vapor framework. Another framework is also available in the market. But we are choosing swift vapor.

Let’s start.

Install vapor in your system.

Step 1. Run below command to install vapor

brew install vapor/tap/vapor-beta

Check whether vapor install or not run below command.

vapor-beta --help

These will be useful command of vapor.

Command only when you are in the project directory.
You can

Created vapor project

vapor new myProjectName

Build vapor project

vapor build

Run vapor project

vapor run

You can configure Xcode. You should be inside the created project directory.

vapor Xcode

When you have made changes in project file or add a new features for the update you have below command.

vapor Xcode

You can run thru local server test API. Out will be “Hello World”

curl http://localhost:8080/hello

===========================================PostgreSQL Setup================================================

Setting Up for local PrortgeSQL. Run below command.

Brew install postgresql

Start local database server.  Run below command

pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start

Stop local database server. Run below command.

pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop

When yow wish to run PostgreSQL as background service with launch you can use brew server. Run below command.

brew services start postgresql

Let start Postgres the by this.

psql -d postgres

Create data base by running below command:

create databas databaseName

Actual command
create databas ashi-app

create user by running below command:- Grant that user the privileges it need with by running below command.

create user username

Actual command
create user ashi-app-user

grant all privileges on database databaseName to userName

Actual command
grant all privileges on database ashi-app to ashi-app-user
===========================================PostgreSQL Setup================================================

===========================================Deploy fresh app on Heroku================================================

Deploy new swift vapor app on Heroku without database.

Consider you already created a Vapor project without the database.

Step 1. Navigate on cd MyApp.

cd myApp
Actual command
cd ashi-api

Step 2. Create a swift version file inside your root project directory. Run below on the terminal.

echo ’5.1.3’ > .swift-version

Step 3. Create Procfile file inside your root project directory.Run below on terminal.

echo ‘web: Run serve --env production --port $PORT --hostname 0.0.0.0’ > Procfile

Step 4.  Add file git  and commit by below command
git add .

git commit -m ‘App Setup’

Step 5. You should generate linux tests file by below command.

swift test --generate-linuxmain

Step 6.  Add again modified in git by below command.

git add .

git commit -m ‘Tests setup’

Step 7. Login on Heroku. Required to create app on heroku for deployment. So we have login on heruko. By running below command we can login.

heroku login

Step 8. Once login done create heroku app. Name must we unique most prefer is app-appname.

heroku apps: create myAppName

Actual command
heroku apps: create ashi-api

Step 9.  Add swift build pack with app. For compiling on hereto we have to add buildback. Heroku doesn’t support inbuild pack for swift.

heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/vapor-community/heroku-buildpack -a myproject

Actual command
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/vapor-community/heroku-buildpack -a ashi-api

Step 10. Find command push changes on sever.

git push heroku master

Now you app and API will available for testing…

===========================================Deploy fresh app on Heroku================================================

======================Set data base with deployed app and next version of deployment==================================

Step 1. Do database configuration. Replace sqlite database with postgreSQL. Because Heroku is not supporting sqlite.

Replace in App->configure.swift. and import in Todo.h TodoController.h

import FluentPostgreSQL

// Configure a PostgreSQL database
    let postgreSQLConfig: PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig

```
if let url = Environment.get("DATABASE_URL") {
  postgreSQLConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(url: url)!
} else {
  postgreSQLConfig = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(hostname: "localhost", username: "app_test")
}
let postgreSQL = PostgreSQLDatabase(config: postgreSQLConfig)

// Register the configured PostreSQL database to the database config.
var databases = DatabasesConfig()
databases.add(database: postgreSQL, as: .psql)
services.register(databases)
```

Step 2. Install the heroku command with home-brew by running.

brew tap heroic/brew && brew install heroku

Step 3.  We can add postgreSQL in app by running command.

heroic addons:create heroic-postgresql:hobby-dev

Step 4. Add update file in git by running below command.

git add .

git commit -m ‘Added PostgreSQL file’

Step 5. Find command push changes on sever.

git push heroku master

The second version will be available for testing with postgreSQL.

======================Set data base with deployed app and next version of deployment==================================

====================== Testing application API ==================================

Step 1. Heroku API path will be. Your https://app-name.herokoapp.com/youapIURL.

Heroku deployed app name

Sample get

apiURL

Data get request

apiURL

Post request from postman.

apiURL

Follow link.

Run get command on terminal.

curl apiURL

Run post command on terminal.

curl -x POST -H “ContentType” : application/json -d ‘{“title:exaple”}’ apiURL

====================== Testing application API ==================================

====================== Other important git and hero log command ==================================

1. Add local repository to heroku.

git remote add heroku appPath

2. See remote push and get repository path.

git remote -v

3. See heroku apps

heroku apps

4. See heroku application log

Number of line

heroku logs -n 100

heroku logs

heroku logs -trail

====================== Other important git and hero log command ==================================

Comment: Please format your answer properly and keep in concise. Also is it a copy-pasted text from any other resource, please mention it and explain your own findings.